# The Intel MKL LINPACK test indicates too big performance

Tags: intel-mkl, flops, linpack

I ran an Intel MKL LINPACK test on an Intel Core i7-14700K processor and got a peak performance of 557 GFLOPS which seems quite unrealistic.

```
Size   LDA    Align.  Average  Maximal
1000   1000   4       155.1099 216.8890
2000   2000   4       425.5128 459.9769
5000   5008   4       379.0532 393.7132
10000  10000  4       427.9537 435.6706
15000  15000  4       426.8314 427.5827
18000  18008  4       545.7857 549.8816
20000  20016  4       553.3485 553.5723
22000  22008  4       548.1379 552.2941
25000  25000  4       549.4231 555.0353
26000  26000  4       550.3011 554.8746
27000  27000  4       542.6011 542.6011
30000  30000  1       532.8780 532.8780
35000  35000  1       534.7904 534.7904
40000  40000  1       557.7524 557.7524
45000  45000  1       557.3916 557.3916
```

The 155 GFLOPS value for the 1000 size seems plausible, but 557 GFLOPS is too high. Does anybody have an idea how it could happen?

I used the following suite:

```
http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/9752/l_mklb_p_2018.3.011.tgz
```

The test was started using the following command:

```
./runme_xeon64
```